# select tr>3 with nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

i want to get  row which it contains  more than 3  columns
how to write xpath  with  nokogiri

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
item='sometext'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(open(item))
data=doc.xpath('/html/body/table/tr[@td.size>3]')
puts data
```

it can not run , help and advices appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The correct XPath will be something like this.

```
doc.xpath('/html/body/table/tr[count(td)>3]')
```

However, in my test program, I can't get Nokogiri to like absolute XPaths like this.  I have to use the double-slash XPath instead.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

html = %{
<table>
<tr class=wrong><td><td></tr>
<tr class=right><td><td><td></tr>
</table>
}

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)
data = doc.xpath('//table/tr[count(td)>2]')
puts data.attribute('class')
```